# icon stretched on mobile devices

Tags: html, css, icons, responsive

I got a problem with some icons (they are anchor links) on mobile devices. If I use the google toggle bar on the desktop version, everything looks fine, when I surf the page on the smartphone, the icon looks slightly stretched.

There might be some problems with the css, but I can't manage to find the problem. I have tried several times to change the height and width, but it does not seem to be working. Anybody got some idea?

Here's the html:

```
<a href="#"><img id="icon" style="max-width:100%" "max-height: 100%"></a>
```

here's the css and the media queries:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 300px) and (max-width:650px) {
#icon {
max-width:100%;
max-height:100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you made 1 html error, 1 CSS error and 1 CSS priority that you must not know. But you should also share the container of your `a` element.

### HTML ERROR

You wrote: `style="max-width:100%" "max-height: 100%"`

```
<a href="#"><img id="icon" style="max-width:100%" "max-height: 100%"></a>
```

But `"` is used to open or close a property. So the way you wrote it, max-height wont ever be taken because style is closed max-width. you should write it like:

```
<a href="#"><img id="icon" style="max-width:100%; max-height: 100%;"></a>
```

### CSS ERROR

Based on your CSS code, mediaquery is not closed. But it should.

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 300px) and (max-width:650px) {
   #icon {
    max-width:100%;
    max-height:100%;
  }
}
```

### PRIORITY

When you are setting `style` property inline (directly in html), it has the priority on css setting. Except if you add `!important` after your css.

So to solve your problem, you have 2 solution. The snippet wont show anything because I dont have your icon. But it is to show the code clearly.

### 1st Solution with inline CSS:

```css
@media only screen and (min-width: 300px) and (max-width:650px) {
  #icon {
    max-width:100% !important;
    max-height:100% !important;
  }
}
```

```html
<a href="#"><img id="icon" style="max-width:100%; max-height: 100%;"></a>
```

### Solution 2 with everything in css:

```css
#icon {
  max-width:100%;
  max-height:100%;
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 300px) and (max-width:650px) {
  #icon {
    max-width:100%;
    max-height:100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<a href="#"><img id="icon"></a>
```

**But this code do not make any sense as you are trying to apply the same max-width and max-height no matter the screen width, it should just be like, based on what you shared:**

```css
#icon {
  max-width:100%;
  max-height:100%;
}
```

```html
<a href="#"><img id="icon"></a>
```

Comment: Thanks. I noticed the html mistakes too. Btw my only goal was to make the icons adjust to different mobile devices, without strecthing them when the screen resizes, in order for them to look nice on mobile screens.

Comment: I will check in a sec and let you know asap. Thank you very much for your patience @MaxGui.